# Drag-drop tabs in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, frameworks

I'm searching for a way to migrate current application from Eclipse RCP framework into default JavaFX. Now when I analyse all the functionallity of Eclipse RCP framework GUI, I found some difficult features to migrate.

- Drag drop tab to other perspective
- Drog drop tab to new screen
- Split screen when a tab (perspective) will be dropped between other perspective
- Resize of perspectives/components by the user

Are all those features possible in default JavaFX?
Does somebody know any framework in pure JavaFX that feels like Eclipse RCP framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the best sollution for our application.
We searched for a javaFx library with the same capabilities as the Eclipse framework. The [tiwulfx](http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/) does just that job. It's easy in use.

Answer (score 1):

We're currently working on such a framework for the [Drombler FX](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/) application framework, but it's still work-in-progress: http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/0.7/docs/tutorial/docking-framework.html#dockingFramework

The Docking framework can even be used outside Drombler FX, but without annotation support and you have to programmtically setup everything. Here is a [sample](http://github.com/Drombler/drombler-commons/tree/master/drombler-commons-fx/drombler-commons-fx-samples/drombler-commons-fx-samples-docking/src/main/java/org/drombler/commons/fx/samples/docking).

Comment: This look promesses. I will look to it when I'm home.

Comment: Is there some link to the sample application (jar file)? Maybe we will use this framework instead of DockFx (because Drombler has more usefull features and documentation).

Comment: There's a Getting Started page: http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/0.7/docs/tutorial/getting-started.html#gettingStarted

Comment: Tnx couldn't build it on my work. Now I have the sample app. Is the drag drop of the tab functionality already been implemented? This is a very important one for our business people.

Comment: Managing the Dockables and Docking Area is largely implemented, the drag'n'drop is in the backlog: https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-fx/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Docking+Framework

Comment: A clean, future-proof solution for dragging tabs is mainly blocked by the following JavaFX issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092098